# Unity Codeless IAP IOS build rejected

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ipad, in-app-purchase

I have a problem using Unity's codeless API in conjunction with IOS.
Apple keeps rejecting the build with the following message:

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
>
> We found that your in-app purchase products exhibited one or more bugs
>   when reviewed on iPad running iOS 12.1 on Wi-Fi.
>
> Specifically, no action takes place when we initiate the purchase.

Some notes:

- I succesfully built and published the app on android.
- The IOS version works with the uploaded build. I can make in app purchases when i run the app on my iphone.
- I have filled in all the required legal/ financial information and have a valid contract for purchases as defined in the ios docs.
- The build is set as "release" and "development build" is NOT checked.

After rejection by apple, all the in app purchases in the developer console are marked as requiring action. 
Specifically it is now showing that the localizations are invalid. However no further information is given. I suspect this is just because the build is rejected?

So, has anyone had a similar problem? Having the app run fine when using the development build on a local phone, but still having it rejected because of the aforementioned reason?

[image: rejection]

Answer (score 0):

In the end i requested i call with Apple to discuss the rejection of my IOS build(s).

It had been rejected 3/4 times with the same reason.

The reason: A problem on their part. They suspect they had a misconfigured environment on their side, which resulted in a not working build on Ipad. 
I did not have to upload a new build, they reused the last rejected one and it was approved within hours of my call.

I suspect that the developers might have been confused, seeing that the app was entirely in dutch. This can seriously cause some confusing, because the representative on the phone had trouble locating some IAP functionality himself like the restore button.

So should you have the same problem:

1. If your app is in a non-english language, specificy where the reviewers have to click for In App Products, where the Restore button is and similar key parts of your app.
2. Request a call with Apple if you are sure that you did everything correctly. Talking on the phone with them really helps speed up the review process and clarify any misunderstandings.

Comment: Hello, we are having the same issue with our game. Identical problem - IAPs don't work on their iPad, but they work on any device we try it on. They rejected our app 4 times. How did you request a call with Apple please? No matter where I look, they only provide contact forms, which I tried filling out, but never got a reply. Same result for appeals through dev console. No reply whatsoever.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you had that option as a button on the app/build rejected page.

Comment: They might have changed it, since I can't seem to find it. Even this website - https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/ is not directly listing any phone numbers. I will try to find some numbers on Google, since filling out those contact forms is like doing nothing. Never got a response :/

Comment: There was never a phone number listed, just an option which said "request a call with Apple". After clicking on it, i was called the next day.

Comment: I filled out the contact form, hoping they will contact us ASAP :/ It's been 24 hours already.